# Rss feed on a Repeater is giving an error

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, rss

I am trying to parce the Rss feed on a Repeater (or Gridview) But I am unable to. Keeps "Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1." error.

```
XmlDocument rssXmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
// Load the RSS file from the RSS URL
rssXmlDoc.Load("http://feeds.skynews.com/feeds/rss/home.xml");
// Parse the Items in the RSS file
XmlNodeList rssNodes = rssXmlDoc.SelectNodes("rss/channel/item");
StringBuilder rssContent = new StringBuilder();
// Iterate through the items in the RSS file
foreach (XmlNode rssNode in rssNodes)
{
    XmlNode rssSubNode = rssNode.SelectSingleNode("title");
    string title = rssSubNode != null ? rssSubNode.InnerText : "";
    rssSubNode = rssNode.SelectSingleNode("link");
    string link = rssSubNode != null ? rssSubNode.InnerText : "";
    rssSubNode = rssNode.SelectSingleNode("description");
    string description = rssSubNode != null ? rssSubNode.InnerText : "";
    // rssContent.Append("<a href='" + link + "'>" + title + "</a><br>" + description);
    rssContent.Append(description);
}
// Return the string that contain the RSS items
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(new StringReader(rssContent.ToString()));
ds.ReadXml(reader);
rssRepeater.DataSource = ds.Tables[2];
rssRepeater.DataBind();
```

Comment: Where do you get the error? Have you looked at the content to make sure it is valid RSS/XML content?

Comment: near ds.ReadXml(reader);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting exception due to this lines of code:

```
XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(new StringReader(rssContent.ToString()));
ds.ReadXml(reader);
```

That behavior is expected because you are trying to read `rssContent` as a XML which **is not**.

This is your `rssContent` after constructing `StringBuilder`:

> Patients will have to wait longer for non-urgent operations and go
>   without some new drugs under plans to be announced today.The European
>   Union's approach to talks which will shape its future relationship
>   with the UK is set to be laid out by European Council president Donald
>   Tusk.Donald Trump's former national security adviser has reportedly
>   offered to testify at hearings into alleged Russian meddling in the US
>   election in exchange for immunity.Islamic State is using civilians as
>   bait for coalition air strikes to create public outcry as the
>   offensive in Mosul continues.Scotland's First Minister Nicola Sturgeon
>   will tell Theresa May in a letter that they need to make a start on
>   arrangements for an independence referendum.Excitement is building for
>   the latest instalment of Game Of Thrones after a new trailer for the
>   show's seventh season was released.Facebook, Google, Twitter and
>   Microsoft have said they will ramp up efforts to fight terrorist
>   content after a meeting with the Home Secretary.A former Power Rangers
>   star has been jailed for six years after killing his roommate with a
>   sword.Five people who died in a helicopter crash in Snowdonia were all
>   from the same family, police have confirmed.Westminster terror killer
>   Khalid Masood died from a single shot to his chest, an inquest has
>   been told.

In order to prevent that issue, you must construct valid `rssContent` XML, or you need to completely avoid using `XmlTextReader`.

I would personally use `XmlSerializer` to deserialize XML, and then I would pass that as a `DataSource` into repeater.

However, this is possible solution, using your approach via `XmlDocument`. Firstly, you need to create class which collection will be `DataSource` of your repeater.

```
public class FeedItem
{
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public string Link { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Then, while you are traversing through the nodes, you need to populate `FeedItem` collection and pass that collection into `repeater`.

```
List<FeedItem> feedItems = new List<FeedItem>();
foreach (XmlNode rssNode in nodes)
{
    var feedItem = new FeedItem();

    XmlNode rssSubNode = rssNode.SelectSingleNode("title");
    feedItem.Title = rssSubNode != null ? rssSubNode.InnerText : "";

    rssSubNode = rssNode.SelectSingleNode("link");
    feedItem.Link = rssSubNode != null ? rssSubNode.InnerText : "";

    rssSubNode = rssNode.SelectSingleNode("description");
    feedItem.Description = rssSubNode != null ? rssSubNode.InnerText : "";
    // rssContent.Append("<a href='" + link + "'>" + title + "</a><br>" + description);

    feedItems.Add(feedItem);
}
rssRepeater.DataSource = feedItems; //Repeater datasource is list of FeedItem objects.
rssRepeater.DataBind();
```

Comment: Thanks fro your reply. Can you please suggest  any code please.

Comment: @Fhd.ashraf I've just edited my answer with possible solution.